# creating dictionary from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have below dataframe

```
a = [1,2,2,3,5]
b = [10,20,30,40,50]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns=['a','b'])
```

I want to generate dictionary like below

```
{1:10, 2:[20,30], 3:40, 5:50}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) + [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

```
{1: [10], 2: [20, 30], 3: [40], 5: [50]}
```

Or conditionally aggregate into a `list` based on number of elements in the series to get exact output:

```
d = df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(lambda s: list(s) if len(s) > 1 else s).to_dict()
```

```
{1: 10, 2: [20, 30], 3: 40, 5: 50}
```